# scanf using with objective c , not asking me to input in console

Tags: objective-c

i am using scanf function in objective using and xCode, but when i run my code it doesn't ask me to enter any values, but it automatically picks up some garbage value and executes the entire program, Can any one help how to make xCode use scanf so that user can enter some value in console before executing the entire code.

```
    int a ;
    int b ;
    int c = a * b;

    NSLog(@"Welcome to the multiplication calculator");
    NSLog(@"\n");
    NSLog(@"what would you like to choose for first value?");
    scanf("%i", &a);

    NSLog(@"\n");
    NSLog(@"What would you like to input for the second value?");
    scanf("%i", &b);

    NSLog(@"Here is your product");
    NSLog(@"\n");

    NSLog(@"a * b =%i", c);
```

console out put

```
2016-02-29 15:57:18.457 HandShakes[51576:12008859] Welcome to the multiplication calculator
2016-02-29 15:57:18.458 HandShakes[51576:12008859] 
2016-02-29 15:57:18.458 HandShakes[51576:12008859] what would you like to choose for first value?
(lldb) 9
error: '9' is not a valid command.
error: Unrecognized command '9'.
2016-02-29 15:57:56.736 HandShakes[51576:12008859] 
2016-02-29 15:57:59.687 HandShakes[51576:12008859] What would you like to input for the second value?
(lldb) 9
error: '9' is not a valid command.
error: Unrecognized command '9'.
2016-02-29 15:58:21.886 HandShakes[51576:12008859] Here is your product
2016-02-29 15:58:25.584 HandShakes[51576:12008859] 
2016-02-29 15:58:27.091 HandShakes[51576:12008859] a * b =-556193768
(lldb)
```

Comment: When you started the project,  did you choose to make it an "OSX Command Line Tool" Project?

Comment: @LouFranco do i have to do this as OSX command line tool project only, can i just not use a iOS project instead ?

Comment: iOS projects have no usable STDIN.

Comment: I'll assume @avi is right because I can't think of what scanf could do on an iPhone.  If you wanted to get text from a textfield to something like scanf, you would have to get the string from it and pass to sscanf instead.

Comment: I have marked this question for close now.